# Perl assign regex match to variable with default value

Tags: regex, perl, default, variable-assignment

I am familiar with assigning a match to a variable using list context:

```
my ($ans) = $somevar =~ m/(somestuff)/;
```

But what if I want to assign a default value to $ans when the match fails? Is there a way to do this well in one expression? Preferably without a conditional operator?

Comment: Did you mean `my ($ans) = $somevar =~ /(somestuff)/;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ans` will be `"default"` if match fails,

```
my ($ans) = ($somevar =~ /(somestuff)/, "default");
```

Note that right side always has `"default"` as last element of the list, waiting to be assigned to `$ans` when regex fails and returns empty list.

Comment: If the match fails, then the argument to `map` is an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the ternary operator will be helpful:

```
my $ans = $somevar =~ /(somestuff)/ ? $1 : 'default_val';
```

Comment: You can achieve much the same result but without a capture by doing `my $ans = $somevar =~ /somestuff/ ? $& : 'default_val';` instead. This is a more legible regex and closer to the OP's request (which wants to assign the _match_ not a capture group (which he may already be using in the match).

Comment: @Danwizard208 - The use of `$&` is deprecated in favor of ${^MATCH} (Perl v5.10+) with the `/p` modifier, as using `$&` "...anywhere in a program imposes a considerable performance penalty on all regular expression matches." Source: [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).  In the case above, the capture *is* the match, it doesn't incur the performance penalty imposed by using `$&`, and it is clearly 'legible.'  Note, also, that it's quite evident that the OP intended to use a capture.

Comment: When I said conditional operator, the ternary operator was what I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

```
my ($ans) = "${somevar}default" =~ m/(somestuff|default)/;
```

Don't actually do this.

Comment: +1 for actually answering without a conditional operator (?:,||, etc.) as the OP requested.

Comment: Well, the `|` in the regular expression is a conditional.